# Can I hide the unins000 files, or else move them to a hidden folder?

Tags: inno-setup

My installer that I made using Inno Script is currently creating two uninstaller files, `unins000.exe`, and `unins000.dat`.

Ideally, I'd like to make these items hidden files, or move them to a hidden folder.

I've managed to do the latter using the following code

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\Uninstallers"; Attribs: hidden;

[Run]
Filename: {cmd}; \
  Parameters: "/C Move ""{app}\unins000.exe"" ""{app}\Uninstallers\unins000.exe"""; \
  StatusMsg: Installing {#MyAppExeName}...; \
  Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: {cmd}; \
  Parameters: "/C Move ""{app}\unins000.dat"" ""{app}\Uninstallers\unins000.dat"""; \
  StatusMsg: Installing {#MyAppExeName}...; \
  Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
```

This creates a hidden folder and places the files in this folder. However, when I go into Control Panel and try uninstalling the program, I get an error message, saying

> An error occurred while trying to uninstall... it may have already been uninstalled

How can I correct this, or else hide the files in the default directory so that the program can be uninstalled, but the files aren't visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`UninstallFilesDir` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstallfilesdir) to specify an alternative location for uninstall files:

```
UninstallFilesDir={app}\Uninstallers
```

---

*(Make sure you remove your `[Run]` section entries).*